# how to see the project you have created using django/ mongo engine on browser?

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

Hi i am beginner to Django, i was trying to create a basic Tumblelog Application with Django MongoDB Engine . i am following this guide http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/

this `url "//localhost:8000/"`
on following these instruction , i keep on getting this message

> "It worked!
>
> Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.
>
> Of course, you haven't actually done any work yet. Here's what to do next:
> If you plan to use a database, edit the DATABASES setting in mysite/settings.py.
> Start your first app by running python mysite/manage.py startapp [appname].
> You're seeing this message because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!"

can anyone help me out what i need to do to move ahead ..?
stuck here for long time .

Comment: You should carry on from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/#build-a-blog-to-get-started you see that message because you probably don't have urls defined, or views (or maybe both)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, open your system console and enter command `mongo` or enter with full path. In my case is `/opt/mongodb/bin/mongo` If all right you should see:

> ```
> MongoDB shell version: 2.2.2
> connecting to: test
> >
> ```

If you enter `show dbs` you see all databases into MongoDB

Secondly, check your settings file. It should be as:

> ```
> DATABASES = {
>    'default': {
>       'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
>       'NAME': 'db_into_mongo'
>    }
> }
> ```

or

> ```
> from mongoengine import connect
> MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
> try:
>     connect('db_into_mongo', host=MONGO_HOST)
> except:
>     pass
> ```

Third, exit from MongoDB console or open a new system console. Move to Django's folder and enter `./manage.py shell` If all right you should see Python console with enviroment of Django:

> ```
> Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 22 2012, 06:12:28) 
> Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >
> ```

Enter `from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField, EmbeddedModelField` if all right you will see nothing

Fourthly, you should return to Django. You must create files models.py, urls.py, views.py into your project's folder and html templates at the templates folder. It must be fill as [examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/#define-the-schema)